# Is there a way to add timer between messages in AWS SQS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, smtp, amazon-sqs

I am developing an email client that uses SMTP server from my customers. I stock the credentials in an AWS RDS database. Customers are able to create mail campaigns, and email have to be sent asynchronously after the campagin creation.

I want to configure a SQS queue to make messages available with a delay of 2 minutes between each message. The purpose is to send the message to a Lambda function able to send the message through SMTP (using the credentials in the database). Thanks to this delay between messages, I can optimize the delivery of the emails. The order of the delivery is not really important.

Unfortunately, I do not find a way to do that. The timers available in SQS are for the entire Queue, or have to be specific for each message. In my case, if i put 100 messages in the SQS queue, I need the first one to be sent immediately, the second 2 minutes after and so on.

Does someone has solutions with this issue ? If SQS is not the right service to manage this need, is there another one available on the AWS platform ?

Comment: Lambda + SQS supports batching: https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2020/11/aws-lambda-now-supports-batch-windows-of-up-to-5-minutes-for-functions/

Comment: I don't want batching. On the contrary, I want to pull one message each 2 minutes from the SQS

Comment: You can schedule a trigger via cloudwatch that basically triggers a lambda which then manually receives a single message from SQS. Apart from that (and deploying your own application and writing all the logic yourself) you do not really have any options left.

Comment: Amazon SQS will not put delays between messages. You should build this delay into your consumer code (so that it only consumes records at a given time interval).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @luk2302 for your answer, it is the good one accordingly to the AWS support team. Using the EventBridge service to trigger the lambda at define timing works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

We can probably achieve this combination of [lambda event source mapping config](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-sqs.html#events-sqs-eventsource) for sqs and lambda [reserved concurrency](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-concurrency.html#configuration-concurrency-reserved) setting.

- Event source Mapping Batch size: 1

  This will allow only 1 message to be sent to Lambda at once.
- Event source Mapping Batch window: 2 mins

  This will allow lambda to be invoked only once every 2 minutes.
- Lambda Reserved Concurrency as 1

  This will allow only one lambda thread to be called at once.

Comment: Apparently, the event source mapping batch window can't be configured this way. We can only configure the MaximumBatchingWindowInSeconds but that does not help here.

Comment: MaximumBatchingWindowInSeconds can be up to 5 minutes right? if we set 2 mins, lambda wont' be invoked more than once in 2 mins?

Comment: No, it is more like: if you choose a batch size of 10 and 2 mins for max batch window, Lambda will wait for 10 messages or for 2 minutes. If there is only 8 messages for 2 minutes, Lambda launch the function.

Comment: @TheoMartinez Thanks. For some reason i thought its an and. I will test it out too later today.